# difficulties with implementing browserify

Tags: npm, gulp, ecmascript-6, browserify, babeljs

i have two .js files,in the same folder.

app.js :

```
import {foo} from 'custom';
foo();
```

custom.js

```
function foo(){
  $('.nav.navbar-nav > li').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.nav.navbar-nav > li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
}
```

And i try to bundle them in gulpfile.js while using babel in the same task.

```
gulp.task('app-scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/js/app.js')
    .pipe(babel({
        presets: ["es2015"]
    }))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'));
 });
```

Can someone help me implementing browserify in this task?i have readen the documentation,but dont know how to apply it when i need it in that specific form.

Have tried this aswell but didnt worked :

```
  const gulp           = require('gulp');
  const babelify       = require('babelify');
  const browserify     = require('browserify');
  const source         = require('vinyl-source-stream');
  const buffer         = require('vinyl-buffer');
  const sourcemaps     = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

  var config = {
    src:      './src/js/app.js', // тут исходник
    out:      './build/js/app.js', // тут выходной файл
    srcmaps:  '/build/maps' // sourcemap'ы сохраняться будут сюда же

  }

   gulp.task('app-scripts', function() {
     const bundler = browserify(config.src, {debug: true})
    .transform('babelify', {presets: ['es2015']})

return bundler.bundle()
    .pipe(source(config.out))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write(config.srcmaps, {addComment: false}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/js'));
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

for some reason the method listed above,which is from documentation didnt work,
but this method worked perfectly,it is aswell from documentation :

```
gulp.task('app-scripts', function() {
const bundler = browserify('./src/js/app.js', {debug: true})
    .transform(babelify.configure({presets: ["es2015"]}));

return bundler.bundle()
    .pipe(source('app.min.js'))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./', {addComment: false}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/js'));
});
```